# Check if user is online from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a login and registration script with PHP and MYSQL and in my database I have
a table "online" where the users id and a timestamp gets stored when they log in.

When thye are logged in they have a cookie.

Now if they are logged (in the "online" table) I need to modify my header, but what would be the best way to check if they are logged in?

I was thinking of something like

```
if(isset($_COOKIE)){ 
    // do something
}else{ 
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Have you tried what you think you should do?.....

Comment: @ Ruddy , Yes, I can get it to work, but im searching for a easier way to do this, something like a function or so :p

Comment: Make it a function then, you have it right.

Comment: not cookie use session because cookie value will exists if session destry

Comment: @ Ruddy, Ok, but how would I check if the function returns true or false?

Comment: Just return it in the if or else. Also that is true. Session should be used instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend storing the logged in user information in the $_SESSION variable.

PHP automatically makes use of the COOKIE value to store the $_SESSION values on the server side, only accessible by your PHP scripts making them slightly more secure.

So, you could store the user id in a SESSION value on one page:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;
```

... and then you can retrieve this on any other pages:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    // Logged in
}
else
{
    // Not logged in
}
```